# CURL: нужно отсеять ненужное из полученного

Tags: curl, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Всем привет. Использую парсер на cURL для сайта, но в итоге получаю всю страницу целиком, а нужно только одно, то что расположено в <span class="counter"></span>. Спасибо за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2):

`cURL` используется для коммуникаций с сервером по протоколу `HTTP/HTTPS` и др. Его задача получить ответ с от сервера. А парсить ответ нужно парсерами, например `libxml2`

Answer (score 1):

Здавствуйте!

Используйте [swat](https://github.com/melezhik/swat), у него:

- генерация запросов происходит посредством curl, поэтому, зная curl никаких проблем с swat не будет
- фактически с точки зрения формирования http запросов swat и есть curl, т.к. прзрачно транслирует все параметры запроса утилите curl
  ( параметры определяются в терминах API утилиты curl )
- а как раз парсинг и валидацию ответов обеспечивает сам swat, с помощью тестовых сценариев, которые пишет пользователь на swat DSL.
- swat очень просто в освоении ( по крайней мере, ддя простых и средних задач ) и маскимально синтегрированнам с curl
- а там где curl "не хватает" swat добавляет много хороших фичей

Вот как может выглядеть ваш пример на swat:

1. решение в лоб, просто хотим , что бы была проврека, что в ответе на GET / приходило ""

$ nano get.txt

```
<span class="counter"></span>
```

**$ swat ./ 127.0.0.1 # запуск тестов**

2. решение с сипользванием кастомного парсера на perl (XML::DOM)

**$ nano get.txt**

```
within: COUNTER FOUND (OK|FAIL)
OK
```

**$ nano hook.pm**

```
set_response_processor( sub {

    my $headers   = shift; # заголовки ответа
    my $body      = shift; # тело ответа

    use XML::DOM;

    my $parser = new XML::DOM::Parser;
    my $doc = $parser->parse($body);

    my $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName("span");
    my $out = "COUNTER FOUND FAIL";

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){

        my $node = $nodes->item ($i);
        $out = "COUNTER FOUND OK" if $node->getAttributeNode("class");
    }


    return $out;

});
```

**$ swat ./ 127.0.0.1 # запуск тестов**

*( PS disclosure - я автор swat )*

Answer (score 0):

Используйте html  [парсер](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)